# ScrollLeft in element with overflow:hidden

Tags: jquery, css, coordinates

I am using a PHP-generated map for a browser game.
I've done the Y coordinates, but I have a problem with the X coordinates.
If the user changes position of the map (by JQuery plugin), the X coordinates scroll with the map.

Here is all the code (sorry for ugly CSS on this site): http://jsbin.com/uWaVANI/1/

The problem are in CSS (I think), because the bar with the X coordinates does not have width 100% and has line breaks. I tried `white-space: nowrap, position: absolute`, but nothing worked.

Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

  $('#mapa_move').kinetic({
    moved: function(state) {
      $('#y_move').scrollTop($('#mapa_move').scrollTop());
      $('#x_move').scrollLeft($('#mapa_move').scrollLeft());
    }
  });


});
```

then it should work. Use scrollLeft instead of scrollRight.

Have a look: http://jsbin.com/uWaVANI/2